# How many Write Ops is neccessary to write blob data(byte array) on appengine datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, blob

I realized it is very expensive to create many new entities(and properties), so I decided to store data chunk (~50kb, zipped Json)in one entity as byte array (blob) to Datastore.

However, I have no idea how many write/read ops might be neccessary to write/read blob data. I wonder whether it is depends on size of blob data or it is just constant write/read ops.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**blobstore data is stored data**

> Stored Data (billable)
>   The total amount of data stored in datastore entities and corresponding indexes, in the task queue, and in the Blobstore.

So you like entities you pay by read, write and not by size

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Datastore

**Costs:** https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing

- Entity Get (per entity)   1 Read
- New Entity Put (per entity, regardless of entity size)    2 Writes + 2 Writes per indexed property value + 1 Write per composite index value
- Existing Entity Put (per entity)  1 Write + 4 Writes per modified indexed property value + 2 Writes per modified composite index value
- Entity Delete (per entity)    2 Writes + 2 Writes per indexed property value + 1 Write per composite index value
- Query 1 Read + 1 Read per entity retrieved
- Query (keys only) 1 Read + 1 Small per entity retrieved
- Key allocation (per key)  1 Small

  1. Write    $0.10 per 100k operations
  2. Read    $0.07 per 100k operations
  3. Small    $0.01 per 100k operations

Also consider storage costs

- Stored Data (Blobstore)  gigabytes per month $0.13  [free limit 5 gb]
- Stored Data (Datastore)  gigabytes per month $0.24  [free limit 1 gb]

Comment: Thank you very much. So it is purely count number of read/write operation, not size of data it write/read.